# Unable to invalidate Asp.Net Session during IdP initiated Single LogOut with WSO2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, wso2-identity-server

we are implementing a Single Sign On process using WSO2 Identity Server. We have both Microsoft and Java web applications involved and we are facing a problem during the Single LogOut processing with Microsoft based web apps. The issue is related to session invalidation on Identity Provider initiated SLO.

This is the scenario:

- WSO2 Identity Server with a single Identity Provider configured
- an Asp.Net MVC application using ComponentSpace SAML2 assembly and Forms authentication marking controllers with the [Authorize] attribute to ensure that users are authenticated to access them.
- the DEMO Java Web application provided by WSO2 to test SSO

The login process works fine. We get a session ID from WSO2 and the user is authenticated landing on WSO2 login form in the first app, and transparently in the sencond one.

In the Asp.Net webapp, when a successfull login occurs, we authenticate the user to access [Authorize] marked controllers calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false); . When the user logout from one of the apps, WSO2 sends a SLO request to other partecipants on a configured URI. When this request is reveived by the Microsoft one, we call the FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); method but the session is not destroyed. If the user refresh the browser page its User.Authenticated property is still True so he can still access [Authorize] marked controllers. This makes sense in my opinion because the caller is WSO2 and not the user browser.

We performed some investigation in the code of the JAR provided by WSO2 for Java applications and it creates a filter on Tomcat implementing a singleton to store WSO2 Session ID relation with Session objects each time a success login operation occurs. When WSO2 request a SLO the filter gets WSO2 Session ID as parameter, accesses the singleton HashTable to retrieve the Session object and calls the Session.Invalidate() method of the session object. If the user refreshes the browser, he gets redirected to login page. We tryied to implement something similar on Asp.Net side but even if we get the Session object on server side and call the Session.Abandon() method nothing happens when the user refresh the browser. He is still marked as authenticated.

I am not very familiar with Cookies and I have the feeling that is something related to them.

Had anyone faced a similar issue? 
Any advice or suggestion will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling FormsAuthentication.SignOut should clear the authentication cookie. I suggest capturing the HTTP flow and confirming whether the authentication cookie has been deleted. The default name for the authentication cookie is .ASPXAUTH. Alternatively it will be the name specified in your web.config's  section. For example, forms name="mycookie" would rename the cookie to mycookie. You shouldn't have to delete the ASP.NET_SessionId session ID cookie.